# Combobox not working with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void comboBox45_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     baglanti.Open();

     string str = "select * from satilikkonutlar where ilanbasligi='" + comboBox45.Text.Trim() + "";

     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, baglanti);
     SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader(); ``           

     while (reader.Read())
     {
         textBox4.Text = reader["fiyat"].ToString();
     }

     reader.Close();
     baglanti.Close();
}
```

The reader is not working help me guys ty.

Comment: You might need to consider of formatting your post. see this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: What makes you think your code is “not working”? It throws an error? What's the error? It doesn't do what you expect? What do you expect? What does it do?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Also your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that you don't need to Close them, since the implicit Dispose will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is incorrect

```
string str = "select * from satilikkonutlar where ilanbasligi='" + 
comboBox45.Text.Trim() + "'";
```

You need the ending '

However, you should consider parameter-izing the query.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
         "select * from satilikkonutlar where ilanbasligi=@value",connection)
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("value",comboBox45.Text.Trim()));
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```